# Fortran multidimensional array syntax

Tags: fortran

Two quick syntax question

Would

```
real(4), ALLOCATABLE:: thing1(:,:)
```

Create a 2D array with 2 columns, an as of yet undefined number of rows, where each element is an array of 4 reals?

Secondly, would

```
real(4) box(3,3),versions,revert
```

Create two arrays of length 4, and 2D array of size 3x3 where each element is an array of length 4.

Comment: Get a good Fortran book, I would suggest Metcalf, Reid and Cohen.

Comment: So this is one of those questions you lazily write at the end of being awake for way too many hours (while reading someone else's code) and your brain decides to all but shut down. I appreciate the lack of name calling, because it's certainly deserved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is no to both.

REAL(4) does not create an array of reals, it determines the KIND of REAL. I refer you to this question: [Fortran 90 kind parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter) to explain this.

Secondly, `thing1(:,:)` does not declare two *columns*, it declares two *dimensions*. The first being rows, the second being columns.

Your second would create a 3x3 array "box" of reals of kind == 4, which is typically precision "float" in C language.

I'm not sure what `versions,revert` is supposed to be.

Also, when creating an array, it is typical, and a little more explicit, to use the `DIMENSION` parameter as such:

`REAL(4),ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION(:,:,:) :: thing1`

which can then be allocated later on as:

`ALLOCATE(thing1(x,2,4))` Assuming you still wanted 2 columns, x rows, and an array of 4 in each location.